# Combine 2 ViewControllers in a single tab of TabBarView and allow back and forth switching within the same tab

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

So I want to do something like this in Xcode (using Swift):

[image]

[image]

There should be a TabBar VC that contains 2 VCs under a single tab. But when one of the tabs is opened, it should show the second VC icon and allow me to switch back and forth among the 2 VCs using the same button.

Like, when you tap on "List", it shows the List ViewController, and the "List" tab then changes to "Map", and vice versa.

EDIT: Incorporated the explanation made by Chan.

Comment: Are you talking about a slide out controller? Check this out https://github.com/KyleGoddard/KGFloatingDrawer

Comment: I'm assuming that you meant when you tap on "List", it shows the List ViewController, and the "List" tab then changes to "Map", and vice versa. But that doesn't seem like a good design and is counter productive to what a tab bar is supposed to do. Is there any reason why they can't be two separate tabs?

Comment: @AMAN77 Not really.

Comment: Then you probably just want  a splitViewcontroller

Comment: Chan, you understood the problem perfectly and that is the requirement of the designer.

Comment: Read Chan's comment. He explained it perfectly.

Comment: @Saad i have got your problem. I have already provided you a solution in below answer. If you want to do it like in that manner i could explain further.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using below Steps:

1. Take a `ContainerView` for your Tabbar's first tab (That may be the ThirdVC).
2. SubClass your `UITabBarController`.
3. Manage one `Global` variable for current showing VC in app delegate or your gloal class.
4. Perform check and update task here (In subclass of your tabbar controller)

   `//Here you can write your logic to update the view controller for first tab. Get reference of FirstVC here or create a delegate from where you can update your first Tab.`

   `override func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item:           UITabBarItem) {
    var selectedIndex = self.selectedIndex
    if selectedIndex == 0
    {
       if currentVC == First
         {
         }else
         {
         }
    }
   }`

Comment: Why does the `UITabBarController` need to be made a subclass of `ContainerView `? Wouldn't this make multiple TabBarControllers? Why not make the internal 2 activities a subclass of `ContainerView ` and link that to `UITabBarController`?

Comment: No.. You have to Subclass 'UITabBarController' to identify the the index selection of your tab bar. Create ThirdVC as a first controller for your first Tab and Add ContainerView To your ThirstVC and in that Container View you will switch between two i.e FirstVC and SecondVC. And on same Tabbarcontroller you will be able to change the Tab icon.